# How can I have Firefox to fill ALL form fields?

Tags: firefox, web-development

I am using the latest Firefox.

I am currently web developing and needs a way to automate form filling. There are multiple fields in my form, but Firefox's only fill per-fields (I need to click per-field and press down). I need it to be able to fill all fields, the whole form, and not just one.

I have set "Remember search and form history" in my privacy setting.

How/what are my options? I have tried add-ons but there are none fit my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
javascript:document.getElementById("yourTextboxId1").value="Yourvalue1";
document.getElementById("yourTextboxId2").value="Yourvalue2";
```

and so on

Simply copy and paste in the omnibox and press enter on the site
(or add it as a bookmark)

Note that if you are testing your own site, it may be easier to set a default value for the textarea

Comment: That's genius. I am testing a framework for front-end I have no access, so I suppose this is the only way :D. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may automate such changes by using the Firefox add-on [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) :

> Allows you to customize the way a web page displays or behaves, by using small bits of JavaScript.